# Can we use "from" after "stop"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, present-participles, reflexives

I want to know the difference between these two items:

> 1. She couldn't stop herself laughing.
> 2. She couldn't stop herself from laughing.

I assume that No. 2 is wrong, but it seems right!

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. As it stands this question is incomplete. Please edit to show what research you did before asking an expert. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical. If there’s any difference, it’s that the first might be used to describe someone who is already laughing and couldn’t stop. The second, on the other hand, might be used to describe someone who was unable to refrain from laughing in the first place.

Comment: This use of _from_ is called "adversative", because it occurs with predicates like _keep/stay/go/come/move/run (away) from, keep/take/bring/move X (away) from_. The _from_ is optional, as Barrie says, and it's entirely at home. But _*She couldn't stop from laughing_ is ungrammatical, so you need an object in this construction.

Comment: An Ngram for "stop (himself) (from laughing") ( http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stop+himself+laughing%2Cstop+himself+from+laughing%2C+stop+from+laughing%2C+stop+laughing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share= ) shows that the version without either the pronoun or the 'from' is far more common than other variants. _Stop_ catenates variously in its different senses: **halt** or **cease**: stop walking; (stop to rest not catenative); **prevent** or **ban**: stop (= prevent) someone fighting. "I had to stop myself from hitting him" sounds better than OP's '2'.

Comment: Both the COCA and BNC have several records of _stop from_ followed directly by the _-ing_ form, and I think I'd be capable of using it myself.

Comment: I think _keep myself_ or _restrain myself_ sound more natural with 'from laughing', though there's little logic as to why when 'I had to stop myself from hitting him' sounds fine to my ears. Perhaps it's the obligatorily punctive nature of _hit_ as opposed to _laugh_. I had to stop myself from telling him. I had to stop myself from leaving. ?/*I had to stop myself from knitting. ?/*I had to stop myself from staying there.